# Creating A GUI from scratch in C++ or assembly

Tags: c++, user-interface, assembly, window, low-level

I have had numerous bad experiences with GUI library

so I would like to know how to create a window from scratch in c++
I am not talking about win32, what I mean is basically create it myself without any external library

is there any way to maybe use a picture or something to create a window
yes I know how hard this will be.

also I read somewhere that library could be made for c++ in assembly

is there a way to create a custom gui in assembly or c++

---

EDIT:
I am aiming at just windows

PS: another reason I want to learn how to do this is because

I might want to actually create an OS. so I would want GUI with that...

Comment: Assembly? Jeez, why don't you just code it machine language?

Comment: The only thing that will help with this project is your user name.

Comment: On what operating system would you like to create this new GUI ? Or are you going to write a new OS from scratch too ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible... If you mean on a desktop with a gui that isn't made up of ascii characters.  Simply you need to interface with a graphics card so unless you're going to write the driver yourself I think you're stuck at least using their library. This means you can go as reasonably low as Dirrect X or Open GL (I favor the later but use linux... so that explains that).

Comment: This question is too vague. Do you mean cross-platform GUI (which *would* require a library) or for a particular OS (or perhaps your own OS), or for a particular graphics card. Love the name Luck though=P. @Jason, what's wrong with an hand-coded assembly GUI?

Comment: @Luck I have some disturbing news for you. You had bad experiences with GUI libraries. Your proposed solution is to change the software. The correct solution is to change the developer. If you can't use a GUI library then you certainly will not be able to write one yourself.

Comment: @Jason what's wrong with assembly, you can do a lot with hardware, it teachs you a lot about computers and how high-level programming languages work, and it's really simple, all it is, is: instruction parameter 1, parameter 2  etc

Comment: I agree, assembley is WAY easier to understand over "high" level languages, the only problem is you have to do EVERYTHING yourself.

Comment: **Just a hint:** those "bad experiences" are due to complexity in the libraries and *every* library has it because it is intrinsic to the problem. In fact, mist of those libraries *protect* you from some of the complexity of the underlying API and problem domain complexity. Do it by hand can be worse. *Much worse*. *// Someone who has done it by hand on Classic Mac OS and with raw X*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to create a window you'll need to interface with whatever windowing system is currently present on your operating system.  This will either require system calls if the window manager runs in kernel space (as is the case in Windows) or some sort of interprocess communication for user space window managers (like X).  To create the window from scratch, you'll need to read up on how these window managers work and what protocols they use.  In the case of X, it shouldn't be too hard to find resources on how the protocol works.  In the case of Windows, your only option might be to use the API, since the internals of the window manager are proprietary.

Comment: http://www.alleystoughton.us/eXene/X-protocol.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You could try perusing the source code to [MenuetOS](http://menuetos.net/) - I believe it's written entirely in assembly and it has a GUI.  Of course, this won't work if you're trying to write a program that runs on Windows, Linux, etc.  But if you want to avoid all external libraries, including interfacing with Windows, you will have to run on the bare metal.

Comment: you did a nice detailed post as well but templatetypedef did wat I was mostly looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you are crazy enough to do this thing in assembly go ahead and install [masm32](http://www.masm32.com/) , it can do basic GUIs like windows/messageboxes etc.

Comment: They said they don't want to interface with Win32...so they'd probably need FASM for non-windows development.

Comment: I thought he meant without MFC and such not !windows development.

Answer (score -8):

You create a window "from scratch" on windows, by calling the "CreateWindowEx" Win32 API.

Comment: Well, no, that doesn't create a window *"from scratch"*. `CreateWindowEx` instantiates an existing window class. If you want to start from scratch, you'd start with [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx).